# Find CSS Float with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to using JavaScript.  How do I determine the float property (left / right) of an image? I think it would be something like this -

```
var positionFloat = $(this).position();
```

I am using the following Caption Overlay code from http://davemcmillan.net.  Great overlay, I just need to be able to float the caption span with the image - left or right.

Thanks!

```
// display image caption on top of image
$("#content img").each(function() {
var imageCaption = $(this).attr("alt");

if (imageCaption != '') {
var imgWidth = $(this).width();
var imgHeight = $(this).height();
var position = $(this).position();
var positionTop = (position.top + imgHeight - 26)
$("<span class='img-caption'><em>"+imageCaption+"</em></span>")
.css({"position":"absolute", "top":positionTop+"px", "left":"0", "width":imgWidth +"px"})
.insertAfter(this);
}

});
```

Comment: Your question doesn't have anything to do with the CSS `float` property does it?  It seems like you're just asking how you find the absolute position of an object so you can manually position something next to it.  If that's the case, please remove the `float` word from both your title and question and that is just confusing people about what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to position a caption on top of an image is to put the image and caption in the same containing div, declare the container as `position:relative` and then use absolute positioning on the text to position it relative to the container on top of the image.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Wvtuz/

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/Family/John-Muir-Trail/Favorite-Landscapes/i-PPwFDdc/0/M/JMT-20130727112047-2595-M.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Rae Lakes on John Muir Trail</div>
</div>

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 140px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of float with the css property. Like this

```
var sideFloat = $(this).css('float');
```